# how to write different post method in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i' using AngularJS v1.4.2. i have 2 html page , they have 2 controller.both controller have save event. how to use  use http post method

first controller i'm calling post method  given below

```
var promisePost = crudService.post(Countries);                          
promisePost.then(function (pl) {
    alert("Sucessfully Inserted")
    getCountry();
    $stateParams.country = "";
}, function (err) {
    alert("NOt Inserted")              
});
```

second controller i'm calling post method  given below

```
 var promisePost = crudService.post(Levels);
 promisePost.then(function (pl) {
     alert("Sucessfully Inserted")
     getLevel();
 }, function (err) {
     alert("NOt Inserted")
 });
```

my app.js

```
myapp.service('crudService', function ($http, RESOURCES) {

//Create new record

this.post = function (Country) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveCountry",
        data: Country
    });
    return request;
}
this.post = function (Level) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveLevel",
        data: Level
    });
    return request;
}
```

});

but this code only take last post method.How to selecet post method properly. Anyone can helpme?

Comment: name both the methods differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `countryPost` and `levelPost` as follows and call those accordingly.

```
myapp.service('crudService', function ($http, RESOURCES) {

//Create new record

this.countryPost= function (Country) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveCountry",
        data: Country
    });
    return request;
}
this.levelPost= function (Level) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveLevel",
        data: Level
    });
    return request;
}
});
```

Comment: Moreover, looking at your code I see in those two methods only URL is geting changed, data is also being change but it is sent via parameter. So if you also provide URL (at least last part of the URL) as parameter. Then I believe it will be a good approach. You do not need two method. As I believe` Code COPY means Bug COPY`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for using services is to return an object from it

```
myapp.factory('crudService', function ($http, RESOURCES) {

 return {
   saveCountry : function(){
       return $http({
       method: "post",
       url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveCountry",
       data: Country
      });
    },
  saveLevel : function(){
     return $http({
     method: "post",
     url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveLevel",
     data: Level
    });
  }
 }
});
```

then inject it into your controller dependencies and use it like :

```
 crudService.saveLevel().then(function(){
   //do some code here
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single post method instead and receive the url to call in it as parameter along with the data. As shown below:

```
this.post = function (data, remainingUrl) {
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + remainingUrl,
    data: data
});
return request;
```

}